# want to send a mail from my server

Tags: email

```
      <?php
      $email2=$_POST['mail'];
      $subject2 = "Information about the user";
      $message2= "name=    " .$_POST['name']."<br>". 
                 "      phone=    ".$_POST['phone']."<br>".
                 "     email=   ".$_POST['mail'];
      $from2 = "nish@gmail.com";
      $headers2 = "From:" . $from2; 
      mail($email2, $subject2,$message2, $headers2 );    
      ?>
```

I want to send the mail from my server . but my problem is NAME , PHONE and EMAIL IS COMING IN SAME LINE .
I WANT LIKE THIS -:

NAME =

EMAIL =

PHONE =

HOW TO EDIT THE MESSAGE PART

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<br>` will be rendered as plain text unless you send your mail as `text/html` which is not what PHP's mail function will do by default, so you need to output newlines (`\n`).

Change the message part like this:

```
$message2 = 'name: '.$_POST['name']."\n";
$message2 .= 'phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"; 
$message2 .= 'email: '.$_POST['email']."\n";
```

You could [**read this**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/php-mail-header-injection-prevention) as a starting point to secure your script against PHP mail header injections.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's mail function sends plain text (unless you set all the needed headers), so you should use `"\n"` instead of `"<br>"`.